# Flot graphing changing tick mark time labels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, graphing

I'm having trouble changing the x-axis tick marks / timestamps to show only hours and minutes, and to remove seconds. i tried changing mode to 'time' and using 'timeformat'; that didn't work. i want to display only minute intervals, any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnse0.png

Comment: If you're not using time mode now, then in what format are your x-axis values?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `timeFormat` in the `xaxis`

This will require the `jquery.flot.time.js` plugin.  If you explore the formatting in this plugin you can create your own however I think this line of code in the `xaxis` will be what you are after:

```
var timeFormat = "%a %d/%m %H:%M";

xaxis: {

       mode: "time",
       timeformat: timeFormat,
       show: true

       }
```